# How to get categories and sub categories in sel referencing many to one relation symfony 3

Tags: symfony, many-to-one, self-reference

I have this entity

```
    class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product",mappedBy="category")
    */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderNr",type="integer")
    */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
    */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category",inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $parent;
```

I want to make a query to get all categories and for each category, the childrens.

I tried many versions of queryes from other questions, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me,please?

In the end i need something like this

```
[Category Parent 1]
   [Childrens]
      [0]
         //details
      [1]
         //details
```